# use Requests to get weather data from virtual crossings API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, get, weather-api

I am trying to access historical weather data from an API. I obtained the API key from here: https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather/weather-data-services#/timeline

I am trying this but I keep getting an Error 404. I am not sure if this is because of a problem with the API or my code.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/London,UK/2021-01-01/2021-03-28?key=AXSSS")
print(r)
```

Documentation: https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/timeline-weather-api/

How can I obtain the data?

Comment: Try it in your browser first. If you get 404 in a browser, then there is no issues with your script.

Comment: It looks like you aren’t passing the API key properly, once you signup on to the website, you should be able to get an API key, with which you can start using the data. Perhaps you can check [this](https://www.getambee.com/api-documentation) from Ambee. It is pretty straightforward And gives you [historical weather data](https://www.gspatial.ai/historical-weather-data.html) that goes up to 5 years+ in history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tested the site you gave and created a account and api key to get London whether data, you can use it too

Code :

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/London?unitGroup=metric&key=PPKBBJ7637X5SNDUG6HZA23X7")

print(r)
```

Output :

```
<Response [200]>
```

now you can access data by json() method too:

```
print(r.json())
```

the output is so Huge, but your problem is 2 things:

1-API key is not correct (i tested)
2-You should buy premium plan

for get a range of dates url will be like this:

```
https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/London/2021-1-1/2021-1-5?unitGroup=us&key=PPKBBJ7637X5SNDUG6HZA23X7
```

and the date range you give , has too much row per request, you should buy premium plan

Otherwise you will get this error in their own website:

```
Your plan allows up to 100 rows per request. This query will return (yyy) rows. Please smaller date range or fewer locations.

Our paid plans offer increased query limits
```

If you don`t want to pay for paid plan you can use this link to use github public apis, a lot of free and without api key you can use for it

[Github public apis](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis#weather)